# Error installing rattle

Tags: macos, installation, rattle

In the bottom it asks for "Selection:" what should i write there?

```
>library("rattle")
Loading required package: RGtk2
R session is headless; GTK+ not initialized.
Rattle: A free graphical interface for data mining with R.
Version 3.5.0 Copyright (c) 2006-2015 Togaware Pty Ltd.
Type 'rattle()' to shake, rattle, and roll your data.
```

open rattle

```
> rattle()

ce)' failed

(R:1244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(R:1244): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(R:1244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(R:1244): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed


etc ... 


(R:1244): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(R:1244): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_screen_get_display: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(R:1244): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(R:1244): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_get: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(R:1244): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_keymap_get_for_display: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
Selection:
```

Then I did install.packages("rattle"); rattle()

And it crashes.

Comment: As @snAtchnAren said, you can open `X11` and use the terminal there to initialize `GTK`. I wrote a brief note on the full installation here: https://gist.github.com/zhiyzuo/a489ffdcc5da87f28f8589a55aa206dd

Answer (score 1):

Just install & open **XQuartz** and then try again!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to open a GUI application on a remote server over ssh but i received above errors. As suggested by @YogiEHunt I've installed XQuartz but the catch is I had to use the -X option while I ssh to the remote server only then the GUI application opens up using XQuartz, without -X option I couldn't open the GUI remotely.

```
ssh -X user@10.0.0.1
user$ application-command
```

After installing XQuartz you have to reboot your system.

The application that opened up using XQuartz is too slow though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to installing Rattle when the problem is that it fails to install RGtk2.  **https://rattle.togaware.com/**

On Linux:

> install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/src/contrib/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
> On Windows:

> install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/bin/windows/contrib/4.1/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip", repos=NULL)
> On Mac:

> install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2021-12-15/bin/macosx/contrib/4.1/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.tgz", rep